# Django: The uploaded images are not Showing in template, says file not found

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, project

I am not able to get the image on my template from database. I had install pillow for supporting ImageField but its not working but It is successfully installed in my file  [proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dM9AU.png).I am getting a broken image instead of uploaded image. Please help me out. note: **I am not using virtual environment**. Below are my codes.
error: [error pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdld0.png) image not found.

Views.py

```
def home(request):
dr_data = dr_reg.objects.all()
data ={
    'dr_data':dr_data
}
return render(request, 'home.html',data)
```

models.py

```
class dr_reg(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField('User',on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
fname = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=False)
lname = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=False)
image = models.ImageField()
specialisation = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=False)
qualificaton =  models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=False)
phone = models.CharField(max_length=12,blank=False,unique=True)
gender = models.CharField(max_length=7,blank=False)
address = models.TextField(max_length=500,blank=False)
state =  models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=False)
city = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=False)
zip = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=False)
email = models.EmailField(max_length=50,blank=False)
dUsername = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=False,unique=True)
dPassword = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=False)

def __str__(self):
    return self.fname
```

home.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'style1.css' %}" type="text/css">
{% block title %}Home{% endblock title %}
</head>

{% block body %}

<div class="container">  
<div class="row">
{% for n in dr_data %} 
<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="card mb-2">
    {% if n.image %}
    <img src="{{ n.image.url }}" class="card-img-top" alt="img">
    {% endif %}
    <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">{{ n.fname }} {{n.lname}}</h5>
        <p class="card-text">{{ n.gender }}</p>
        <p class="card-text">Qualificaton: {{n.qualificaton}}</p>
        <p class="card-text">Specialisation: {{n.specialisation}}</p>
        <p class="card-text">Email: {{n.email}}</p>
        <p class="card-text">City: {{n.city}}</p>
        <p class="card-text">Contact: {{n.phone}}</p>
        <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">3 min ago:</small></p>
        <a href=""
           class="btn btn-success">
            Book Appointment
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
</div>
{% endblock body %}
```

settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT =  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'image') 
MEDIA_URL = '/image/'
```

urls.py

```
from django.views import View
from . import views
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
  path('', views.home, name="home"),
  path('about', views.about, name="aboutus"),
  path('contactus', views.contactus, name="contact"),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
  urlpatterns+= static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I have add this settings.DEBUG in every url file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the first problem would be that you are not specifying the upload_to parameter in your imageField so the image file doesn't get saved anywhere.
It should look something like this

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to="folder-in-media-root/")
```

Secondly, You need to install the pillow library to use the Django imageField

```
pip install pillow
```

Here's a link to the docs which you could take a look at
ImageField:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ImageField
FileField:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField

Comment: I have installed pillow already the problem was with uploadto="" . Thank you it is working now